# Strange behavior when using mask-image with a gif

Tags: css

I'm attempting to use the mask-image property that goes along with mask-clip with a gif, but the end results are a static image unless I am actively holding my mouse and dragging the cursor across the screen.

Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/NicolasNewman/pen/WNOdJMa

```
#content {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
        mask-clip: border-box;
        mask-size: 100% 100%;
        mask-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/gMRlMq46JgmtrjvoX1b9KMiEk_CS8h0bk6CDOQ4F56M0-ilVM4kws98BaQCYtl0ZN_UGwVcpz9BwGNfLPqjVUREkwLT2Dck")
}
```

Why is it exhibiting this behavior? Is there a way I could have it remain animated without the user's input?

Comment: I see the behavior described in Firefox (Windows 10) but on Chrome/Edge it continues to animate without user interaction as desired (though of course I needed to add -webkit- to the mask properties).

Comment: Interesting. Same results for me. Do you have any ideas on how I can investigate further?

Comment: Afraid not, I can't find anything that tackles this and trying hacks like forcing a requestAnimationFrame and the like regularly don't force anything to happen, only user interaction like click (anywhere in the viewport it seems) as well as the moving you described make it work. Weird.

Comment: In any case I submitted a bug to Mozilla's issue tracker. It's either unintended behavior or a performance optimization that isn't documented (from what I could find).